# Trouble comparing a table to itself to get elapsed time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
incidentID           timestamp             lognumber     code
265             2019-02-09 22:02:55         21452666    Active   
265             2019-02-09 22:11:12         21452677    Cleared   
277             2019-02-09 22:20:11         21453151    Active   
277             2019-02-09 22:21:15         21453160    Cleared   
307             2019-02-09 22:52:45         21453992    Active   
307             2019-02-09 23:05:06         21453997    Canceled   
307             2019-02-09 23:08:02         21453998    Active   
307             2019-02-09 23:08:05         21454002    Cleared
```

Every entry in logID is a unique value, and sequential.

I would like to compare the table to itself, such that it appears as the following, which would allow me to get the time elapsed between active and resolved timestamps.

```
incidentID       active_timestamp          resolved_timestamp        active_code    resolved_code
265             2019-02-09 22:02:55         2019-02-09 22:11:12         Active      Cleared   
277             2019-02-09 22:20:11         2019-02-09 22:21:15         Active      Cleared   
307             2019-02-09 22:52:45         2019-02-09 23:05:06         Active      Canceled   
307             2019-02-09 23:08:02         2019-02-09 23:08:05         Active      Cleared
```

Currently I am performing an INNER JOIN on incidentID between an Active table WHERE code = 'Active' and a Resolved table WHERE (code = 'Cleared' OR code = 'Canceled'), ORDER BY incidentID. However, the resultant table looks like this:

```
incidentID        active_timestamp      resolved_timestamp  active_code resolved_code
265             2019-02-09 22:02:55     2019-02-09 22:11:12     Active      Cleared   
277             2019-02-09 22:20:11     2019-02-09 22:21:15     Active      Cleared   
307             2019-02-09 22:52:45     2019-02-09 23:05:06     Active      Canceled  
307             2019-02-09 22:52:45     2019-02-09 23:08:05     Active      Cleared 
307             2019-02-09 23:08:02     2019-02-09 23:05:06     Active      Canceled
307             2019-02-09 23:08:02     2019-02-09 23:08:05     Active      Cleared
```

As you can see, the joined table doesn't properly handle incidentIDs with more than one active/cleared code.

How do I join this table to itself so that it looks like the middle table above?

Comment: Did you try pivoting the table ?

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
 select incidentID, max(case when code='Active' then timestamp end) as active_timestamp
        max(case when code='Cleared' then timestamp end) as resolved_timestamp
        from table
group by   incidentID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *    
from
(select * from table) x,
(select * from table) y
where   x.code = 'Active'
and x.incidentID = y.incidentID
and x.timestamp <> y.timestamp
```

Hope it helps! `table` is same table

PS: sorry, not tested!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, you can use CTE

```
With c as(
Select incidentID
      ,max(timestamp) as active_timestamp
From Table 
Where code like 'Active'
Group by incidentID
), d as(
Select incidentID
      ,max(timestamp) as closed_timestamp
From Table
Where code in ('Cleared','Canceled')
Group by incidentID
)
Select incidentID
     , active_timestamp
     , resolved_timestamp 
From c LEFT JOIN d ON (c.incidentID = d.incidentID)
```

If you find problems like this try to divide and conquer instead of trying to do everything with one query

Also, this can be resolved with subqueries or by pivoting your table.

Answer (score 0):

When I first looked at your question, I thought it is easy - self join will work.
But soon I noticed that `incidentID = 307` should output two rows.

```
307 first_active_timestamp cancel_timestamp
307 second_active_timestamp clear_timestamp
```

Needs a little improvement to self join ...

```
select a.id
     , a.timestamp
     , isnull(ca.timestamp,cl.timestamp)
     , a.code
     , isnull(ca.code,cl.code) 
from (select * from incident where code='active') a
left join (select * from incident where code='cleared') cl
on (a.id=cl.id and a.lognumber < cl.lognumber)
left join (select * from incident where code='canceled') ca
on (a.id=ca.id and a.lognumber < ca.lognumber)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. However, it continues to behave oddly if the incidentID codes go Active-Cleared-Active-Cleared, rather than Active-Canceled-Active-Cleared. I'm sorry for not making apparent that this was possible in the original post.

Comment: The SQL in my solution cannot handle Active-Cleared-Active-Cleared. So you are saying it could be Active-Cleared, Active-Canceled-Active-Cleared, Active-Cleared-Active-Cleared. Is it possible to Active-Cleared-Active-Cleared-Active-Cleared, Active-Canceled-Active-Canceled-Active-Cleared, Active-Active-Canceled-Cleared, or Active-Active-Cleared-Cleared ... ?

Comment: For every incidentID, it is always a sequence of Active followed by a Cleared or a Canceled. It is never Active followed by Active, or Cleared/Canceled followed by Cleared/Canceled.

Comment: So is it possible to be Active-Cleared-Active-Cleared-Active-Cleared?

Comment: Yes, or Active-Canceled-Active-Canceled-Active-Canceled and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This pivots your data into columns. then looks for the earliest [Active] time and latest [Cleared] time by Incident ID.  Then gets the difference in minutes.  (This keeps the Canceled event in the same row as the incident)

```
With cte As
(
   Select 
      incidentid,
      Case When code = 'Active' Then [timestamp] End As Active,
      Case When code = 'Cleared' Then [timestamp] End As Cleared,
      Case When code = 'Canceled' Then [timestamp] End As Canceled
   From #tbl
)
Select 
   Incidentid,
   Min(Active) As Active,
   Max(Cleared) As Cleared,
   Max(Canceled) As Canceled,
   DateDiff(MINUTE,Min(Active),Max(Canceled)) As cancel_tLapse,
   DateDiff(MINUTE,Min(Active),Max(Cleared)) As tLapse
From cte
Group by incidentID
```

Result:

```
Incidentid      Active                      Cleared                     Canceled                cancel_tLapse   tLapse
265             2019-02-09  22:02:55.000    2019-02-09  22:11:12.000    NULL                    NULL            9
277             2019-02-09  22:20:11.000    2019-02-09  22:21:15.000    NULL                    NULL            1
307             2019-02-09  22:52:45.000    2019-02-09  23:08:05.000    2019-02-09 23:05:06.000 13              16
```